How to use Drizzle-zod types in Nuxt?
I have a big monorepo with 3 nuxt applications that share a common server (written in Hono). The structure of my app is:
.
├── apps
│   ├── web1
│   ├── web2
│   └── web3
├── package.json
├── packages
│   └── base-layer
├── README.md
├── server
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── shared
    └── types.ts

Inside server/src, I am using drizzle-zod to convert my database types to zod.
export const users = pgTable('users', {
  name: text('name').notNull(),
  email: text('email').notNull(),
  password: text('password').notNull()
})

export const createUserBody = createInsertSchema(users, {
  password: z.string().regex(passwordPattern, 'Password too weak')
})


// and this is re-exported in shared/type.ts
export { createUserBody } from '../server/src/schema/users';

But I can't use this zod schema in the frontend directly without running into dependency issues. Nuxt throws a 500 error shown below:

EDIT: here's the vue logs:
WARN  [Vue warn]: Property "createUserBody" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
at <Container class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center" data-v-inspector="pages/login.vue:64:3" > 
at <Login onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
at <Anonymous key="/login" vnode= { __v_isVNode: true,
...

